# Everything "invisible" when launching map from launcher

Tags: cryengine

I downloaded the CryENGINE SDK, and I tried the map Forest from within the editor and it worked fine. However, if I launch it from the Launcher using the console it looks like this:

[image]

I can use the weapons (although they are invisible) and interact with objects despite not seeing them.  I also did my own map and had the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that some resource files(such as textures or shaders) are missing in the directory in which you execute the launcher? or whatever path the map is (i know nothing about cryengine). It looks as if the diffuse layer is not being applied and it's only rendering light layers, but this is just a speculation, I couldn't really tell.

Comment: Wouldn't it then not work in the editor as well? Because I'm not using the debug build I compiled myself but the build that came with the SDK

Comment: i don't know, but probably there is some field in the editor config telling "use this path as default for loading resources", and the launcher lacking of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think CryEngine probably compile shaders ( this in CryEninge can take a lot of time ) or engine have some problems with compiling shaders. Look in the log.

Comment: Yes definitly check logs, you will see the error right away.  Unless it's a problem with video card/drivers?

Comment: press ~ and check the errors in the console. Also make sure you have fxc.exe in the same dir, and rc.exe in rc folder